# How do you convert an object with duplicate keys to JSON/String?

Tags: javascript, object, duplicates, key

**Imagine you have an object like this:**

---

```
var obj = {
    name: "Mike",
    name: "George",
    age: 24,
}
```

---

Converting this to JSON with `JSON.stringify(obj)` yields:

---

```
{"name":"George","age":24}
```

This causes loss of data and isn't something we want.

Converting this to a string with `toString()` yields 
`[object Object]`
, which isn't what we want either.

How does one go about this?

---

PS: *I am aware that objects can't have two identical keys.*

---

So after some brainstorming with the nice users that have commented here, a simple way to deal with this is to just turn it into a string manually. Like this:

```
var obj = `
    name: "Mike",
    name: "George",
    age: 24,
`;
```

Then just parse it to your heart's content. For me personally, this could be a way to do it. However, this will obviously depend on the user-case.

```
var obj2 = {};
str = str.split(",").map(e => e.replace(/(\")/gi, "").trim());

str.forEach((e, i) => {
  var temp = e.slice(0, e.indexOf(":"));
  if(obj2[temp]) obj2[temp].push(e.slice(e.indexOf(":") + 1).trim());
  else obj2[e.slice(0, e.indexOf(":"))] = [e.slice(e.indexOf(":") + 1).trim()];
})
```

The code above just splits the string based on some desired separator and processes the given array further. This might be a indelicate way to solve the question, but it works for my scenario :/. It yields the following JSON-object:

---

```
{"name":["Mike","George"],"age":["24"]}
```

Comment: at the moment you declare your object, the second `name` overwrite the first, unrelated to `JSON` converting

Comment: Yes I am aware of this :) Perhaps a way to go about this is to convert it to a txt file or something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So after some brainstorming with the nice users that have commented here, a simple way to deal with this is to just turn it into a string manually. Like this:

```
var obj = `
    name: "Mike",
    name: "George",
    age: 24,
`;
```

Then just parse it to your heart's content. For me personally, this could be a way to do it. However, this will obviously depend on the user-case.

```
var obj2 = {};
str = str.split(",").map(e => e.replace(/(\")/gi, "").trim());

str.forEach((e, i) => {
  var temp = e.slice(0, e.indexOf(":"));
  if(obj2[temp]) obj2[temp].push(e.slice(e.indexOf(":") + 1).trim());
  else obj2[e.slice(0, e.indexOf(":"))] = [e.slice(e.indexOf(":") + 1).trim()];
})
```

The code above just splits the string based on some desired separator and processes the given array further. This might be a indelicate way to solve the question, but it works for my scenario :/. It yields the following JSON-object:

```
{"name":["Mike","George"],"age":["24"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. the `"name"` value is the second value assigned to `"name"` key in javascript object or JSON. try to use `obj.name` it will be `"George"`

This is workaround to do what are you need.you can use `"_"` or any unused symbol.

```
const obj = {
  name: 'ahmed',
  _name: 'elmetwally',
  title: 'js dev',
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/\_/g, ''));
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of this. However, is there really no other way to keep the values within the identical keys besides manually changing the keys?

Comment: I updated my code. but if you can do it. how to parse the string again.

Comment: Nice, but it still doesn't solve anything. You see, I have this large object provided to me by somebody else. It has 1000s of keys, and 1000s of these keys are duplicate keys, but they have different values. I wanna keep all of the values, but simply re-assign them to a different key if it's a duplicate. :/

Comment: actually no one can provide you with js object have 1000 duplicate key. the obj variable in the question have two keys not three keys. please provide me with object have duplicate keys (accessible) and i will create function to genrate JSON with duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

Right after your object is defined, the second "name" key will override the first "name" key.

You can re-structure your object like this:

```
var obj = {
    name: ["Mike","George"],
    age: 24,
}
```

or

```
var arrayObj = [{
        name: "Mike",
        age: 24,
    },{
        name: "George",
        age: 24,
    }]
```

and use the built-in function for string in js to get your expected result.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for replying. I know this can be done. However, just imagine that someone has provided you with an object of this sort. The object has 10000 keys and let's say 1000 duplicate ones. You don't want to lose any data. You want to keep all the values within the duplicate keys too, but re-assign them to a new, but different key if it's a duplicate.

Comment: hmm if the input is object, you can not keep the object without loss. you can try to use another type to store data

Comment: When I think about it, a way to deal with this is to simply put quotation-marks around the entire object and just parse it manually. :/

Comment: whenever your data come into an object, it will be overrode :) not depending on before parsing or after parsing....

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple method to convert a string representation of the object into an array of key-value pairs.

It's not a general method, but it should work fine for an object with no nesting.

```js
let result = document.getElementById('result');

let jsonStr = `{ name: "Mike", name: "George", age: 24 }`;
result.innerHTML = `jsonStr: "${jsonStr}"\n`;

// strip out '{}'
let jsonClean = jsonStr.replace(/{/g, '').replace(/}/g, '');
result.innerHTML += `jsonClean: "${jsonClean}"\n`;

// split jsonClean into array of key-value strings
let kvStrings = jsonClean.split(',');
result.innerHTML +=
  `kvStrings: ${JSON.stringify(kvStrings)}\n`;

// form array of key-value pairs
let kvPairs = kvStrings.map(kvstr => {
  let [key, value] = kvstr.split(':').map(el => el.trim());
  
  // strip double quotes or convert to number
  if (value.includes('"')) {
    value = value.replace(/"/g, '');
  } else {
    value = Number.parseFloat(value);
  }
  
  return [key, value];
});
result.innerHTML += `kvPairs: ${JSON.stringify(kvPairs)}`;
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```